# JavaFX add node (Programm) after or before another node (XML)

Tags: java, javafx

If I append a node like this:

```
HBox child = new HBox();
HBox fooBar = (HBox) doc.lookup("#fooBar");

fooBar.getChildren().add(child);
```

It might work but not the way I want it to because I want to define the position. What if I wanted the child before or after fooBar?

```
<HBox>
  <HBox id="first"></HBox>
  <HBox id="fooBar"></HBox>
  <HBox id="last"></HBox>
</HBox>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fooBar.getParent().getChildren()` returns a `ObservableList` which, as it is inheriting from `java.util.List` has a method `add(int index, E element)`(further information in [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html?is-external=true))

Adding your new Node at the right position may do the trick.
The following code adds the child before fooBar.

```
int fooBarIndex = fooBar.getParent().getChildren().indexOf(fooBar);
fooBar.getParent().getChildren().add(fooBarIndex, child)
```

Comment: Of course, `fooBar.getChildren().indexOf(fooBar)` will necessarily return `-1`, since you're not allowed to add a node as a child of itself - but that is more of a problem with the question than with the answer.

Comment: Thanks! That is great.